# Centra DB to IPhone App / Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database

I'm trying to find some reading materials on how to connect an IPHONE app to a central DB-Server such as SQL-Server.

I know about SQLite, and the other methods of storing Data in the device itself. What I'm really interested is for the application to interact with a central database server. Are there any sort of objects such as SQLClient in .net or do I need to go through sending off HTTP-Requests and deserializing json/xml?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know the answer to your question, but even if you find that it would be not recommended to do so, since its always better to use an httprequest solution,

Encapsulating the database implementation is always the way to go, since database implementation could change rather quickly adding a layer over it is recommended

That goes without saying that you will not be able to do caching by accessing the database directly, which is also a drawback

am sorry this is not the answer you are looking for, but you should re think on how you are going to implement your solution,

Answer (score 0):

Preform a httprequest to a php script or similar and parse JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a REST interface to bridge the 2 together, and as you said deserialize responses depending on the format, if it's json or xml.

From Device side, make GET/POST requests to your script, which responds the query results back to the app and handle them accordingly.